# why Vuetify rule take 0 as not set in lazy validation?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vee-validate

I'm asigning defaults values from API but when the value of v-text-field is 0 the :rules tag take this as not set: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymTDo.png)

here is my code

```
<v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
    <v-text-field type="number"  :rules="incapacidadRules" min="0" v-model="editedItem.incapacidad" label="Incapacidad"></v-text-field>
</v-col> 
<v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
    <v-text-field type="number" min="0" :value="editedItem.descanso"  :rules="descansosRules" v-model="editedItem.descanso" label="Descansos"></v-text-field>
</v-col> 
<v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
    <v-text-field type="number" min="0"  :rules="permisosRules" v-model="editedItem.permiso" label="Permisos"></v-text-field>
</v-col>
```

and my rules

```
incapacidadRules: [
    v => !!v || 'Incapacidad Requerido'
],
descansosRules: [
    v => !!v || 'Descansos Requerido'
],
permisosRules: [
    v => !!v || 'Permisos Requerido'
],
```

When I manually set the value to 0 then there is no problem with the rule.

Answer (score 2):

0 is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). So `!!0` == `false`. For your rules, maybe use `typeof v === "number" ? v : 'Incapacidad Requerido'` rather than !!v.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this: as Tanner mentions 0 is a falsy, So when you set the value as

```
editItem(item){
    this.editedItem.faltas=item.faltas;
}
```

and the `item.faltas` is 0 the v-text-field is recognized as false, but with values differents to 0 there is no problem. So, you need to set always the values as string:

```
editItem(item){          
    this.editedItem.faltas=`${item.faltas}`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider `!~a` is **true** for `a >= 0` and **false** for `a < 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parseInt()` or other variants of type conversion to validate on the numeric value and not the string value. `v-text-field>` represents string values and 0 is falsy hence the rule being triggered.

```
(v) => { 
    if (parseInt(v) >= 0) return true; 
    return 'Incapacidad Requerido'; 
},
```